# FragmentManager and SupportFragmentManager both used

Tags: android, android-fragments

I did not want to use the 'support' stuff, I am only aiming API level 14 (4.0) and up. So I did not use the `SupportFragmentManager`. Everything went well, but then I was using the `DrawerLayout`, which is in the support library.

Then the issue began: to use this, your activity has to be `FragmentActivity`. You have to use `getSupportFragmentManager`. So I use that one for the drawer.

But I use `getFragmentManager` for managing fragment replacement.

I do an `addToBackStack()` in the replacement, but when I press 'back', the activity closes. 
When I do the same in an other activity that does not extends `FragmentActivity`, it works as expected (the fragment is popped).

I now added `OnBackPressed()` and do a pop there if there is a fragment. Do not like this workaround, but ok.

I was wondering, does anyone else had this situation before and/or has tips?

Edit:
I completely switched to the support one, but I will keep the question here, because I'm still curious

Comment: What makes you think you need to use `FragmentActivity` to use `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: I have no idea, it's been a year, that's like 7 years in software engineer years :)